# WireMock client throws JsonException on HTTP 308 permanent redirect response from server

Tags: java, cucumber, wiremock

I'm running the two following commands in the debugger:

```
mockServerClient.register(put(urlEqualTo("apiEndpoint")).willReturn(ok()));
mockServerClient.getStubMapping(UUID.fromString("d8fb42c5-927d-476b-bbb3-20f92a31bd05"/* 
UUID copied from register response  */));
```

Construction of wire mock client:

```
var mockServerClient = new WireMock("mock-server.ourInternalDomain.com", 80);
```

The `register` call returns a full object (copied from debugger, and yes, different UUID from above as different instance of call):

```
{
  "id" : "50434254-76db-45c6-8601-60399544833b",
  "request" : {
    "url" : "apiEndpoint",
    "method" : "PUT"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200
  },
  "uuid" : "50434254-76db-45c6-8601-60399544833b"
}
```

But the following `getStubMapping` call returns a 308 permanent redirect response:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : { },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (String)\"<html>\r\n<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n\"; line: 1, column: 2]"
  } ]
}
```

Calling the mock server via Postman yields valid results, so can't repro the issue.
Why am I getting valid response for `register` but not for `getStubMapping`?

Java17, Cucumber

Comment: Use "https" schema, and ensure port (mandatory field) is changed: `mockServerClient = new WireMock("https", baseUrl, 443);` I'm still not sure why I can hit the non-https endpoint via Postman with no issues though. Replicated redirect issue with RestAssured's RequestSpecificationBuilder. And logging and using that same request via Postman still works...